# Dependency property based on POCO property that already notifies

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, inotifypropertychanged

I have a dependency property exposed in my control that takes its value from another object that already implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

Is there any way to tell WPF to subscribe directly to this object, or do I have to plumb the change notifications myself?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm may be unclear on your question, but you could do:

```
control.SetBinding(YourDependencyProperty, new Binding("YourProperty") { Source = poco });
```

You can also set Mode to TwoWay to pass values back to the POCO.